# Javascript css display none display block transition

Tags: javascript, css

`CSS` can't make a transition from `display: none` to `display: block` for that i'm trying to make it using javascript i don't want to use `visibility: hidden` and `height: 0` or `transform: scale(0)`

for that i'm using javascript to make a transition from `display: none` to `display: block`

The code below work when i add the `active` class the transition working fine, But when i remove the class `active` the transition it's not working

How can i make the transition work in both when i add and when i remove the class active using javascript and css ?

```js
let parents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');

parents.forEach(p => {
    p.addEventListener("click",() => {
        if(p.classList.contains('active')){
            setTimeout(function () {
                p.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("visually");
                
              }, 20);
                p.classList.remove("active");
           
        }else{
            p.classList.add("active");
            setTimeout(function () {
                p.nextElementSibling.classList.add('visually');
              }, 20);
        }

    });
});
```

```css
.link-inner {
cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.parent.active+.toggle {
    display: block;
}

.parent.active+.visually {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="link">
    <div class="link-inner parent">
        <div class="linkText">
            <h4>Title</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="linkInfo toggle ">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">link 1</a>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="link">
    <div class="link-inner parent">
        <div class="linkText">
            <h4>Title</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="linkInfo toggle ">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: U could add an "inactive" class and create an event listener for that class as well and if you remove the "active" class you add the "inactive" which has also a transition in css defined.

Comment: @HangoverSoundSound can you give me an example please

Comment: When you remove the active class the styles are immediately updated to `display: none`. You need to trigger the transition to `opacity: 0` on click and then set a timeout so once the transition is complete you remove `display: block`

Comment: @Tom can you give me an example how to do it

Comment: @TakashiAnji can you give an example with the toggle because i used but the transition doesn't work can you please give me an example with the toggle an make the transition work

Comment: @user3018000 [this repl.it](https://replit.com/@TakashiAnji/stackoverflow2#script.js) show my way to work with toggle. But it look more complex than Tom's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually really nearly there. You just had to swap the calls when removing classes and add a bit more of a delay in your setTimeout

```
let parents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');

parents.forEach(p => {
    p.addEventListener("click",() => {
        if(p.classList.contains('active')){
            // remove the class that sets opacity so it fades away
            p.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("visually");
            setTimeout(function () {
                // remove the class that sets display: block after the opacity is gone
                p.classList.remove("active");
                
              }, 500);
        } else {
            p.classList.add("active");
            setTimeout(
                function () {
                    p.nextElementSibling.classList.add('visually');
                },
                20
            );
        }

    });
});
```